# How do I record data FK'd to two other models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Using the 'Pizza' example, I have a Toppings Model, I have a PizzaTemplate Model and a 'Pizza', and now I need to record an amount of topping for each pizza.

For Example I have a 'Pepperoni Pizza', I need to record 1 scoop of cheese, 1 scoop of pepperoni. Then I might have a 'Pepperoni Pizza - Extra Pepperoni' which would be 1 scoop of cheese and 2 scoop of peperoni, it uses the same selection of toppings, which have already been defined, I just need to record how much of each.

My Current models.py looks like this:

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class PizzaTemplate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)


class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Im guessing I need another model like so:

```
class Ingredients(models.Model):
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza)
    topping = models.ForeignKey(Topping)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to achieve this or there's a smarter way?

The idea is to be able to create a new pizza, choose a topping template, and then specify varying amounts of each topping for this particular Pizza Option.

My idea was to dynamically create the form for each input on page load, eg, get the list of toppings and generate a label & input box for each, but the more I go down this path the more I feel like I'm going against the grain and there's probably a better/more obvious method.

I was looking at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships but I'm not sure this relates perfectly to what I'm attempting.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using model forms.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/

```
class PizzaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pizza
        fields = ('name',)

class IngredientsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    pizza = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=PizzaTemplate.objects.all())
    toppings = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Topping.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

    class Meta:
        model = Ingredients
        fields = ('pizza', 'toppings', 'amount')
```

In your view, you can use these forms to create a new pizza and specify the ingredients for the pizza.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import PizzaForm, IngredientsForm

def create_pizza(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pizza_form = PizzaForm(request.POST)
        ingredients_form = IngredientsForm(request.POST)
        if pizza_form.is_valid() and ingredients_form.is_valid():
            pizza = pizza_
```